# How can I resolve those errors in Vercel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, vercel, postcss

Im trying to deploy a website but I always have those errors no matter what hoste I use,

here as u can see :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgnIM.png)

I tried to understand what means postcss, so after found some stuff about that, I put it on my package.json and installed dependence with npm but nothing change, can someone help please ?

Thank you very much

Edit : Yes I'm sorry, here my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow": "^7.18.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "css-select": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.17",
    "postcss-pseudo-class-any-link": "^7.1.6"

  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --expose-gc --max_old_space_size=12000 start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "postcss": "^8.4.17",
    "postcss-pseudo-class-any-link": "^7.1.6",
    "sass": "^1.55.0"
  }
}
```

and the log from vercel :

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-pseudo-className-any-link/-/postcss-pseudo-className-any-link-7.1.6.tgz - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'postcss-pseudo-className-any-link@https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-pseudo-className-any-link/-/postcss-pseudo-className-any-link-7.1.6.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 This package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-10-11T11_12_38_905Z-debug-0.log
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
Running "npm run build"
> my-app@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build
sh: react-scripts: command not found
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 127
```

Comment: Good day to you sir. You would benefit from reading and applying: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask when asking a question. There is a lot missing in it, most notably: package.json (just to see your deps), npm's output as text (so they can search easily) instead of image, and that log that is mentioned in output seen in the image under 'A complete log of this...'
Otherwise all that people can do is make wild shot guesses what went wrong since they have no way of getting the complete information from that log.

I am gonna give you a quick chance to provide those and not insta-flag.

Comment: I edited it, thanks and sorry for the trouble

Comment: Great! As I mentioned this file could be usefull to people trying to debug this:     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-10-11T11_12_38_905Z-debug-0.log
This is the npm log file, it might show more than the console as the message above it explains :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no package called `postcss-pseudo-className-any-link`. Please check your `package.json` file and remove the package.

There is package called `postcss-pseudo-class-any-link`, maybe try installing that.

Comment: Yes I installed postcss-pseudo-class-any-link already, but it seems not working...